# Should a delegate declare the custom protocol it implement?

Tags: objective-c, delegates

I have created a `UITableView` subclass `SliderTableView` and created a `NSObject` subclass `SliderDataSource` that act as the `UITableViewDataSource delegate`.

I want to extend the `UITableViewDataSource protocol`. Should I declare the extended protocol in `SliderTableView` or in the `SliderDataSource`. If I declare the protocol in `SliderTableView` I will need to import it in my delegate, If I declare it in the delegate I won't need to import it but it sounds fishy to declare the protocol you obey to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your question is, in which *header file* it should be defined, you should define it in SliderTableView.h. `SliderTableView` determine the content of the protocol, knows what it needs and so on. So it is the right place. The import is correct, because there *is* a dependency.

Anyway you can define the protocol in an extra header file for that protocol, too.